# How can I install openMP on my new MacBook Pro (with Mac OS Catalina)?

Tags: macos, clang, openmp, llvm, homebrew

I installed Xcode (and also the command line tools) but terminal says (when I'm compiling):

```
gcc -o task -fopenmp task.c
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

I tried to install openmp via brew but people say that it's not available anymore on homebrew, they suggest to try

```
brew instal llvm
```

But I get the same error.
I tried also in the boneyard

```
brew install homebrew/boneyard/clang-omp
```

but the repository doesn't exist anymore.

Could you help me?
I just need to learn openMP, I don't think that is so difficult to install...

Thank you!

Kind regards,

Nico

Answer (score 5):

To build with OpenMP support, you need to make sure you're not invoking Apple's clang from Xcode. Even if you install `llvm` or `gcc` via brew, you should try `gcc -v` and `clang -v` in your terminal session. Both likely invoke Apple's version.

You can use GNU gcc or LLVM; both are available via brew. If you use LLVM, you'll also need to install `libomp`.

#### GNU gcc (currently at version 9)

```
brew install gcc
gcc-9 -o task -fopenmp task.c
```

Note that you invoke this version of gcc explicitly by suffixing `gcc` with a `-` and the major version number, e.g.: `gcc-9`

#### LLVM

Brew installs LLVM as keg-only so that it doesn't conflict with Apple's version. You'll therefore need to make sure you invoke the right `clang`. You'll also need to specify where the `libomp` library is located.

```
brew install llvm libomp
`brew --prefix llvm`/bin/clang -L`brew --prefix`/lib -o task -fopenmp task.c
```

Answer (score 3):

This https://iscinumpy.gitlab.io/post/omp-on-high-sierra/ suggest to do the following:

```
brew install libomp
```

To install the OpenMP runtime components/libraries.

Then, when compiling:

- use `-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp` in place of `-fopenmp` in the compile step (`-c` option)
- add `-lomp` to the linking step

Note that the above page also mention that CMake 3.12 or later will automatically find the right way of adding OpenMP on MacOS:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(openmptest CXX)

add_executable(sample sample.cpp)

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(sample PRIVATE OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
```

*Note: I didn't test any of this but it sounds relatively sane*

Comment: Hi, no, sadly it doesn't work.
A lot of random errors as before:

Comment: Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/info
/usr/local/share/locale
/usr/local/share/man
/usr/local/share/man/man1
/usr/local/share/man/man7 if I write brew install libomp

Comment: @Nico Battelli You need to setup write permissions for /use/local and its contents.

Comment: @NicoBattelli `brew doctor` should tell you the issues you may need to fix to use `brew`.

Answer (score 0):

`brew install gcc`

then type `gcc` in your terminal and hit the tab button twice.

you should see multiple gcc versions e.g. `gcc` `gcc-10`

then find out which one is from Homebrew e.g. type `gcc-10 --version` in the terminal should output something like this:

`gcc-10 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_3) 10.2.0 Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Finally use that compiler to compile your e.g.:

`gcc-10 -o task -fopenmp task.c`